# Neo4j sum function not working properly

Tags: neo4j

I have a CSV like below

I have import the CSV to neo4j

[image]

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM "file:///testset.csv" AS line WITH line

CREATE (c:Company {name: line.`company`})
MERGE (s:Supermarket {name:line.`supermarket`})


CREATE (c)-[r:trade{product:line.`product`,country:line.`country`,price:line.`price`}]->(s)
SET r.price = tofloat(r.price)
;
```

so would like to produce a graph relationship to view the relationship between company and supermarket.

```
MATCH (c:Company)-[r:trade]->(s:Supermarket)
RETURN c,sum(r.price),s
```

However, the output is below

[image]

My Expectation is

[image]

> The difference is it will group by Company A as they are identical
>   except the price. I would like to know is it possible for Neo4j to
>   merge it? Or it's only possible to show on table? Thank you for your
>   help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In graph databases, you generally want to avoid having duplicate nodes. I think it would be better to re-import such that you only have one of each distinct node (:Company and :Supermarket).

Try reimporting, using MERGE instead of CREATE for the company so you'll only have one distinct node per company.

With that change, your query should now produce correct tabular results (correct sum between company and supermarket), but if you want to visualize a relationship with the sum of the prices, you'll need to use [APOC Procedures for virtual relationships](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_virtual_nodes_rels), since such a relationship with the sum does not actually exist in the graph.

```
MATCH (c:Company)-[r:trade]->(s:Supermarket)
WITH  c, sum(r.price) as totalPrice, s
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(c,'trade',{price:totalPrice}, s) YIELD rel
RETURN c, rel, s
```

Comment: Thank you so much!